# Is it possible to express roots of polynomials in terms of other roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, radicals

It is well known that not all roots or zeroes of polynomials degree $5$ or higher cannot be expressed in radical forms and must be approximated. Let $Q$ be such a polynomial and $σ$ be a root of $Q$. Let $d$ be the degree of $Q$. If $P$ is a degree $d_2$ polynomial that is a composite function of $Q$ and $d | d_2$. Is it possible to express the roots of $P$ in terms of $σ$ if $(d_2/d)<5$?

For example, let $Q=x^5 + 2 x^3 + x^2 + 1$ be one of these polynomials and $σ$ be a root of $Q$. Let $P = x^{10} + 4 x^8 + 2 x^7 + 4 x^6 + 6 x^5 + x^4 + 4 x^3 + 2 x^2 + 2$. Is it possible to express the roots of $P$ in terms of $σ$ given that $P = Q^2 + 1$?

I would expect something similar to that of $x$ and $x^2+1$: The roots of $x$ are $0$, and the roots of $x^2+1$ are $±i$. $\sqrt (0-1) = ±i$. Maybe something similar could be apply in the example I gave?

Thanks for help in advance.

Here is a particular example of a degree twelve polynomial I constructed using roots from a cubic polynomial:

$Q=x^3 - 7 x - 7$. One root of $Q$ is given by:

$σ = -(7^{2/3}*(1 + i\sqrt(3)))/(2^{2/3} (3*(9 + i\sqrt(3)))^{1/3}) - ((1 - i\sqrt(3)) ((7/2)*(9 + i\sqrt(3)))^{1/3})/(2*3^{2/3})$

(note that $σ$ may not be expressible in radicals sometimes)

If $P=x^{12} - 5 x^8 - 14 x^6 + 76 x^4 + 224 x^2 + 349$, then one root of $P$ is given by:

$\sqrt((σ-i\sqrt(3)))$.

Comment: A root of $Q$ satisfies $P(\sigma)=1$. I doubt that there is a simple connection between the roots of $Q$ and those of $P$.

Comment: Follow up to @YvesDaoust. If you look at a much simpler situation it may help. Take eg $Q(x)=x^2 + 3$ and $P(x)=Q(x)^2-4$. The roots of $Q$ are $\pm\sqrt{-3}$, and the roots of $P$ are $\pm\sqrt{-1}$, $\pm\sqrt{-5}$ and the fields these generate are independent. This seems to me to be the typical situation.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes, but I was referring to field extensions. For instance, $u$ is a polynomial and then try to find the roots of $u^2+3$ in terms of $± \sqrt{-3}$. For instance, if $u=x^2-x$, what are the roots of $u^2+3$? Furthermore, is there connection between the roots of $x^2+3$ and $u^2+3$?

Comment: You must tell us precisely what you mean by "in terms of". I gave it this simple meaning: $\alpha$ is given in terms of $\beta, \gamma, \dots, \zeta$ iff $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\beta,\dots,\zeta)$. I then gave you an example where $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\cap\mathbb{Q}(\beta,\dots,\zeta)=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The roots of $Q=x^2+3$ are $σ=±\sqrt{-3}$. Suppose  $u=x^2+1$ (this will provide a better example than $x^2-x$.). Then the roots of $P=u^2+3$ are $±\sqrt{-1±σ}$. Thus, the roots of $P$ are expressible in radicals in terms of the roots of $Q$. Hope this makes more sense now.